# Kotlin: Why does the !! operator generate null checks when compiling for the jvm?

Tags: java, jvm, kotlin

I am using https://javap.yawk.at/ to inspect Kotlin generated bytecode. I found that whenever the !! operator is used , a corresponding null check is generated. For example, for the following kotlin code:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    var a : Int? = null;
    println(a!!+2)
}
```

this code is generated:

```
public final class MainKt {
    public static final void main(@NotNull final String[] args) {
        Intrinsics.checkParameterIsNotNull((Object)args, "args");
        final Integer n;
        final Integer a = n = null;
        if (n == null) {
            Intrinsics.throwNpe();
        }
        System.out.println(((Number)n).intValue() + 2);
    }
}
```

My question is: Why does a null check need to be generated. Would'nt the JVM anyway throw a NPE whenever it encounters a method call on a null receiver? Why another redundant check is necessary?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The semantics of the `!!` expression is that it performs a null check at the specific location where the `!!` operator is used, and throws a specific kind of exception (`KotlinNullPointerException`, a subclass of the standard `NullPointerException`) if the expression being checked is null. Throwing a specific exception subclass makes it clear that the exception is caused by a failure of a null check in the `!!` operator, and therefore makes it easier to track down the cause when it occurs in production.

Even if Java did throw an NPE in a subsequent expression (which it may or may not do, depending on how you use the value to which you applied the `!!`), it would be a generic NPE, not a Kotlin-specific one. Also, the line number in the stacktrace could be different from the line number on which `!!` was used, making it harder to understand the problem.

Comment: Thanks. I now understand why the null check is generated. However, couldn't the null check be optimized away when it is coupled with a method call in the same line, like in the above example.

Comment: No, because the method call will not throw a `KotlinNullPointerException`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that JVM can't throw NPE early enough. You don't always use the nonnull type immediately. Using null assertions can prevent null from propagating through your code too far to trace. Suppose you have this class

```
class Foo {
    var bar : Bar = null
    fun foo() {doSomethingWitNonNullBar(bar)}
}
```

Here the bar is not immediately used after it's set in a `Foo`. If you accidentally wrote something like `foo.bar = null` and invoked `foo.foo()`later on a different thread, it will be really hard to know where this null come from. This may seems silly, but it will quickly become a real deal when your code is a mix of lots of nullable types and nonnull types. Without assertions you can't be confident if the type is not null.

Answer (score -2):

I see only one reason: string operations.

```
val s = null;
val s2 = "abc" + s;     // abcnull
val s3 = "abc" + s!!;   // NPE
```